# Is it possible to perform lazy broadcasting which is followed by a reduce operation?

Tags: python, numpy

Sometimes array processing involves operations that include both, first *broadcasting*, then *reducing* along a specific axis. By using the natural broadcasting syntax, this will create intermediary arrays that contain all dimensions, the final ones as well as the ones that will be reduced, which might lead to significantly increased memory usage (beyond what is necessary from the algorithmic point of view).

Consider the following example function will computes the MSE between two vectors:

```py
def mse(x, y):
    return np.mean((x - y)**2, axis=-1)
```

Now, if I have a collection of vectors and want to compute the pairwise `mse` between all vectors, I can do that in the following way:

```py
N, d = 100, 3
vectors = np.random.uniform(size=(N, d))

pairwise = mse(vectors[None, :, :], vectors[:, None, :])
```

However this creates an intermediary array `x - y` of shape `(N, N, d)` which might consume too much memory, especially if `d` is large. From the algorithmic point of view, this is not necessary and only `(N, N)` memory is required:

```py
pairwise = np.empty(shape=(len(vectors),)*2, dtype=vectors.dtype)
for i in range(len(vectors)):
    pairwise[i] = mse(vectors[i:i+1], vectors)
```

This however means that the concise syntax `mse(vectors[None, :, :], vectors[:, None, :])` cannot be used anymore.

So my question is, is there any way to instruct Numpy to perform the broadcasting lazily and only evaluate it when a certain reduce operation is encountered (e.g. `np.mean`)?

Comment: No.  `numpy` is python, with new classes and functions, but no change in evaluation syntax and order.

Comment: @hpaulj Sure, I meant if there is some utility that let's me do something like `vectors = lazy(vectors)` and from now on all operations on `vectors` won't return the immediate result but instead remember the operations and operands that were encountered and only perform them once a reduce operation like `np.mean` is encountered (but in a smart way, without expanding to the `(N, N, d)` array). I could create such a `lazy` wrapper class myself, but the part which cannot be done outside of Numpy is the smart broadcast/reduce which doesn't require full expansion of the operands.

Comment: `tensorflow` allows you create a `model` with unevaluated code, which is later evaluated in a batch  mode.  I haven't used it, but have seen lots of SO where people had problems creating an array from unevaluated tensors.  If you want write code in that 'algorithmic` way, use `numba` to create a custom complied function.  Think of `numpy` like a LEGO set.  Lots of clever building blocks, but no way to mold your own blocks.